# How to create dynamic tag based on props with Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

How can I make a component similar to vue-router `router-link` where I get the tag via props to render my template ?

```
<my-component tag="ul">
</my-component>
```

Would render:

```
<ul>
  anything inside my-component
</ul>
```

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use a built-in `component` element like so:

```vue
<component is="ul" class="foo" style="color:red">
  anything inside component
</component>
```

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: Just don't use `is` as the prop name (no: `<my-component is="ul">`). Instead call it something like `myTag` (yes: `<my-component myTag="ul">`).

Answer (score 16):

**EDIT:** Please check @krukid answer, it is a better solution, I didn't know about `component` element when I answered

**Render function ways:**

You need to create a "wrapper component" that use a render function.

```
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.component('wrapper-component', {
  name: 'wrapper-component',
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement(
      this.tag,   // tag name
      this.$slots.default // array of children
    );
  },

  props: {
    tag: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
});
```

then in any other template just use as follows

```
<wrapper-component tag="div">
  <span>All this will be rendered to inside a div</span>
  <p>
    All 
  </p>
</wrapper-component>
```

and that should render to this

```
<div>
  <span data-v-4fcf631e="">All this will be rendered to inside a div</span> 
  <p data-v-4fcf631e="">
    All 
  </p>
</div>
```

To know more about render functions please see [official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)

Comment: Is there a solution that does not require using the render function?

Comment: @rayrutjes, see krukid's answer.

Comment: btw, `this.tag` won't work in your code, instead `this.$props.tag` would do.