# Vue: choosing html element type with props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue component which can be either a button or a link, I want to have a prop called 'type' which accepts a string 'button' or 'link', is there a way to programatically render such component without a hacky v-if?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create dynamic tag based on props with Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41748934/how-to-create-dynamic-tag-based-on-props-with-vue-2)

Answer (score 0):

component is might be want you need:

```js
<component v-bind:is="type"></component>
```